# Reading multiple partitions (year/month/day) from S3 in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a S3 Dataset that is partitioned on year, month and date.

```
year=2022/month=06/day=1/
year=2022/month=06/day=2/
year=2022/month=06/day=3/
...
year=2022/month=07/day=09/
year=2022/month=07/day=10/
year=2022/month=07/day=11/
```

I want to read multiple partitions from the S3 bucket based on any given date range in a Spark Dataframe. I don't want to read individual date partitions and keep on union'ing them.

I know of a solution in PySpark (using `dateutil.relativedelta`) but I want to understand, how to do the same with Scala for any given date range?

**What I have implemented so far**

1. For weekly runs, generate 7 individual date paths
2. For monthly runs, generate glob patterns: yy/MM/*

```scala
def calculate_query_dates(spark:SparkSession, runDate: LocalDate, programType:String): (LocalDate, LocalDate) = {

    val dayOfWeek = runDate.getDayOfWeek.getValue()

    if (programType == "Month") {
        val last_day_prev_month = runDate.minusMonths(1).`with`(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
        val first_day_prev_month = runDate.minusMonths(1).`with`(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
        
        first_day_prev_month, last_day_prev_month

    } else if (programType == "Week"){
        
        val last_day_prev_week = if (dayOfWeek == 7) runDate else  runDate.`with`(TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))
        println("last_day_of_week:::", last_day_of_week)
        
        val first_day_prev_week = if (dayOfWeek == 7) runDate.`with`(TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) else  runDate.minusDays(7).`with`(TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
        println("first_day_of_week:::", first_day_of_week)

        first_day_prev_week,last_day_prev_week
    }
  }

def generate_S3_paths(spark:SparkSession, s3_bucket_name: String, program_type: String, s3_prefix: String ="", start_query_date: LocalDate, end_query_date: LocalDate): List[String] = {
    
    val monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM");
    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");
    
    if (programType == "Month"){
        val list_s3_paths_month = s3_bucket + "/" + s3_prefix + "year=" + start_query_date.getYear.toString + "/" + "month=" + start_query_date.format(monthFormatter).toString + "/*" 
        
        list_s3_paths_month
    } else if (programType == "Week"){
        val list_dates = (0 until 7).map(start_query_date.plusDays(_)).toList //generate a range of dates between start_query_date and end_query_date
        val list_s3_paths_week = list_dates.map((i: LocalDate) => s3_bucket+"/"+ s3_prefix + "year=" + i.getYear.toString + "/" + "month=" + i.format(monthFormatter).toString + "/" + "date=" + i.format(dateFormatter).toString + "/")
        
        list_s3_paths_week
    } //good to add a logic for dynamic date range
    
}
```

**Question**

1. How to generate S3 path for any date range; for example: 3rd November 2021 to 15th March 2022
2. If I am using [parquet(paths: String*)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#parquet(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) to read from the S3 Paths (for eg: list_s3_paths_week), will it be a sequential read or a parallel read?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, is the question how to generate a date range to date in scala? Have you tried googling it? Or ...like, experimenting with it? Or is it spark specific? Did `*` not work for you?

Comment: I have tried using wildcard in the days partition; however, the dynamic date ranges can range across days, across months and also across years. Let's say I want to read partitions from 3rd November 2021 to 15th March 2022. Wildcards won't work in such cases

Comment: Then figure out which paths to read first, and then them all. Whether it will be sequential or parallel, depends on your cluster configuration, and the specific transformations you are doing.

Comment: @Dima, 
1. which cluster configuration are you talking about? I will be using 32 nodes of r5.8xLarge EMR Cluster and working with around 2TB data. 2. So, you are suggesting to form all the S3 paths between 2021-11-03 and 2022-03-15 and then load the data?